# regular expression in c++ 11

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I wrote this line fore regex in c++ 11:

```
regex a("(\\w\\d)+(\\W)?(*)(\\W)?(\\w\\d)+");
```

I want to find phrase like A * B
(A or B could be number) and space are optional

but at this line it throw an exemption!
what wrong whit this line of code?

Comment: read about [Kleene Star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star), or `*` in regexes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape the asterisk (not sure if it should be escaped with a single or double backslashes, but correct me if I'm wrong!):

```
regex a("(\\w\\d)+(\\W)?(\\*)(\\W)?(\\w\\d)+");
                         ^^
```

The asterisk is a character in regex to indicate the occurrence of a character or group of characters 0 or more times.

Using `(*)` alone isn't valid, and causes the "exception" :)

Still though, to make it work, you need this regex:

```
regex a("(\\w)+(\\W)?(\\*)(\\W)?(\\w)+");
```

This should match your string `A * B`

`\w` (or `\\w`) in your case matches both numbers and alphabets, so don't worry about using `\\d`, because the way you wrote it, it will match one alphanumeric character (or underscore) accompanied with a digit.

Last, if you only want to match and not capture, this should still work:

```
regex a("\\w+\\W?\\*\\W?\\w+");
```

**Addendum:**

```
regex rx{ R"((\w)+\W?(\*)\W?(\w)+)" };
cout << regex_replace("A * B", rx, "($1$2$3)");
```

Comment: that regex won't work..you should use `\s` and what about digits!

Comment: Thank you!I want to find A * B and replace with (A*B) do you have any suggest?

Comment: @Anirudh `\\W` takes care of spaces, and `\\w` is alphanumeric (both digits and letters).

Comment: @Aryan Could you try the one I added to my answer? I don't know C++11, but searches brought me to this syntax ^^

Answer (score 1):

`*` is a reserved character in regex that will match a character 0 or many times.  You need escape the `*` character using `\\*`  to match the `*` symbol

E.g.

```
regex a("(\\w\\d)+(\\W)?(\\*)(\\W)?(\\w\\d)+");
```